# How to set order_by only on ManytoManyfield in detailview (Django)?

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I have 2 models `Class` and `Student`. One field within the `Class` mdel has a `ManytoManyField` relationship with `Student`. I want to order the manytomanyfield with `first_name` in the template. How can I do it?

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Class(models.Model):
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    # many other fields
```

views.py

```
class Class_detailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    login_url = '/'
    model = Class
    template_name = "attendance/content/teacher/class_detail.html
```

template

```
<div class="row ml-auto mr-auto">
  <h6>{{ object.subject }}</h6>
  {% for student in object.student.all %}
    <h6 id="class-detail-text" class="mt-2">
      {{student.first_name}} <-- want to order here
    </h6>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

right now the names render like this:

```
Freaky  Albon  Bucky
```

I want it to order like this:

```
Albon   Bucky  Freaky
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `ordering` in the model meta

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('first_name',)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just override the `queryset` attribute of your view.  You can also use the `Meta` attribute of the `Student` model if you **always** want the ordering to take place any time you access it.

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch

class Class_detailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    queryset = Class.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('student', queryset=Student.objects.order_by('name'))
    login_url = '/'
    model = Class
    template_name = "attendance/content/teacher/class_detail.html
```

See docs on `prefetch_related`:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

As an aside, usually `ManyToManyField`'s are pluralized, so consider changing it to `students`.

Comment: The `.order_by('student__name')` only affects the `Class` instance rather than the `student` objects

Comment: @ArakkalAbu sorry you're right! I updated the answer, I didn't test it but I think that would work? I personally don't like the `Meta` way because I think ordering to be more explicit in the view. I'd also always make sure to prefetch if you're accessing m2m field details.